# Filter "top" commands result on basis of command column

Tags: bash

I am trying to get specific commands processes instead  of getting all process but I am unable to filter results on basis of command column.
I want it to do it with a command. I don't want to go with the way in which we press "o" and then give something because I have to run it from  a bash script.

what I have tried

```
top -b -n 1 | grep 'php-cgi, httpd'
```

I want to get process in which commands are httpd and php-cgi only

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
top -b -n 1  | grep 'php-cgi\|httpd'
```